# I need the help identifying what type of bike I have a notes specialized but that's about it

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

Serial number M1Ei13897

[image: BB area]

[image: BB area 2]

Components:

- Marzocchi bomber 03 exr comp fork shox
- Guizzo carbon fiber oversized 31.8 handlebar
- SRAM x-5 gears  specialized 1:1 ratio
- Azonic Outlaw wheels with tubeless tires MTB also will
- Tektro Auriga hydraulic discs
- Cannondale handlebar grips
- Raceface cranks

[image: detail photo]

[image: one more photo]

Comment: Are you positive its Specialized?  I'm thinking its a nice collection of parts on a more generic frame.   You could try registering it at https://www.specialized.com/us/en/bike  and see whether its accepted or not.

Comment: Its raceface cranks

Comment: I found some indication that Specialised serial numbers are completely random, and have no inherent decoding system.  You can contact Specialized customer support with the serial number and ask them to look it up.   Worth an attempt!

Comment: @Criggie Now that the photos have been posted, there's a Specialized logo on the dropout.

Comment: Make sure to adjust the quick release levers so that they are fully closed

Comment: Is that shift cable supposed to be running over the screw head like that?

Answer (score 3):

The frame is somewhat like a 2003 Specialized Hardrock, no later than that because the 2004 frames seem to have additional bracing between the NDS stays for the disc brake.

However, it looks like every single component has been changed or upgraded since. Therefore you answered your own question; you have a frame, a Specialized, with a list of components as you described.

See John Burgess' [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58635/i-need-the-help-identifying-what-type-of-bike-i-have-a-notes-specialized-but-tha/58782#58782) for a more precise match on frame i.d.

[image: https://cdn.bicyclebluebook.com/bikepedia/2003-Specialized-Hardrock-Pro.jpg]

Comment: What do you think is the value of the  Bike

Comment: @Adrian please read the [tour]  We don't do valuations here because they change, and are highly regional and seasonal.  If you want to know what its worth, list it on craigslist or ebay or gumtree for $1 start.  Its worth what someone wants to pay for it.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Its hard to tell if the top tube is the exact same. but this has both disc and canti brake set ups like your frame.

This is an old Rockhopper, around like 2002.

Comment: I think the frame is indeed a rockhopper, not what I said, but I don’t think I can edit that into my answer without stealing the credit, d’oh.